# add dropdown dynamically in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to create a canvas that allow writing chemical formula 
the idea is to use hexagone which can be clicked on his summit to change the atom. So when we click on the hexagone summit a dropdown menu appear in which we can choose the atom.
[image]
I can add a dropdown menu as a sibling to the canvas and position it thanks to a container but how could I dynamically (on mouse click) add a dropdown menu on canvas.

an example of the dropdown menu
[image]

Any idea, reflexion are welcome.
I've made a simple hexagone which can be the represntation of a cyclohexane for 
[image]
 those who have code suggestion

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas').getContext('2d'),side = 0,
    size = 100,
    x = 100,
    y = 100;

canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(x + size * Math.cos(0), y + size * Math.sin(0));

for (side; side < 7; side++) {
  canvas.lineTo(x + size * Math.cos(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6), y + size * Math.sin(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
}


canvas.stroke();
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: What do you need exactly? How to show an element from an event? How to detect a click event on a canvas particular area/shape? How to position your element correctly relative to the canvas? Please narrow down your question, we don't write free code, and note that all the questions I enumerated have been asked and answered many times in here.

Comment: @Kaiido The question is how to place on mouse click an html element on canvas

Comment: And you know how to position an element relatively to an other? You also know how to listen to a click event? Then you don't need us. Otherwise, search a bit, as I said these questions have been answered many times already. And if you are confused because the element behind is a <canvas> and not a <div> or <img>, then don't worry, it's just the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. Have an invisible dropdown box already on the page, *outside* of the canvas element
2. On click of the canvas, check and see if the user clicked on a hexagon. (check if distance from mouse click is within the bounds of any hexagons on screen)
3. If it is within the bounds of a hexagon, move the invisible dropdown box to the location of the hexagon and then turn it visible.

If you need an example let me know.

I've coded an example in the following CodePen: https://codepen.io/darrylhuffman/pen/OqmBja

Here is the logic I am using to determine if the user clicked on an atom, and then to move the dropdown box:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    let atom = atoms.find(a => distance(a.position, { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY}) <= a.r)
    atomDropdown.classList.remove('hidden')
    if(atom){
       atomDropdown.style.left = atom.position.x + 'px'
       atomDropdown.style.top = (atom.position.y + atom.r) + 'px'
    }
})
```

Be sure to read into all of my code in the CodePen though, because I believe you may want to take the approach I did when it comes to generating atoms/bonds/etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is one more problem which is that I want to add a dropdown only on hexagon summit because it's the only place where you can change atom. If you have an example I'll be more than happy

Comment: @soniamaklouf I've updated my answer with some code that is sure to fix your problem. Hope it works for you! :)